# Get all Childrens of a JSON in C# using NewtonSoftJson

Tags: c#, json, parsing

com User!

My Json:

I want to giveout all name -> username1 and username.

I used C# and newtonsoft.json

I hope somebody can help me.
I tried it like this but it didnt work:

```
"kind":"UserList",
"data":{
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"test1",
         "author_flair_text":null,
         "mod_permissions":[
            "all"
         ],
         "date":1506648472.0,
         "rel_id":"rb_r8mbbr",
         "id":"t2_x6piz",
         "author_flair_css_class":null
      },
      {
         "name":"username2",
         "author_flair_text":null,
         "mod_permissions":[
            "all"
         ],
         "date":1553842373.0,
         "rel_id":"rb_18jmxnv",
         "id":"t2_a64nduq",
         "author_flair_css_class":null
      }
   ]
}
}


dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(source);
             var mods = obj["data"]["children"].Children();
             foreach (var mod in mods)
             {
                 string modss = obj["data"]["children"][mods]["name"].ToString();
                 Console.WriteLine(modss);
             }
```

Comment: You should provide the error you’re encountering and also the stack trace. Better yet, run it through the debugger and step through each line. That should make the issue clear.

Comment: The json you pated is missing starting ’{‘  Without that it’s not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have got a ‘`mod`’ as an object. All you need to do is access the “`name`” property of the ‘`mod`’.

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(source);
             var mods = obj["data"]["children"].Children();
             foreach (var mod in mods)
             {
                 string modss = mod["name"].ToString();
                 Console.WriteLine(modss);
             }
```

Note: The json you’ve pasted in the question is missing a starting ‘{‘ and without that it’s not valid.